# MySQL date format and parsing

Tags: mysql, database, date-format

We have two websites using the same MqSQL database. One in English the other in Czech. We use dates which are shown in the database as `2011-01-22` for example. When called via PHP the format is displayed as: **22 Jan, 2011**. That's fine for our English website but we need the Czech version to show for our Czech pages. Any ideas how to change how the date is parsed? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function in PHP. Try this:

```
<?php
SetLocale(LC_ALL, "Czech");
$datum = StrFTime("%d %B, %Y");
echo($datum);
?>
```

The code above prints **"22 leden, 2012"**, just like your English date format.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Current answer should work fine for displaying date in Czech.

Comment: The line I use to call the date is this, can you modify it please? Many thanks! `<?php echo date('d M, Y',strtotime($get_user_info['date_added']));?>`

Comment: Ok JoeW, try this:  `<?php echo StrFTime("%d %B, %Y", strtotime($get_user_info['date_added']));?>`   Hope, this works.

Comment: You can put it in the same php file where your echo statement is. Just  make sure that comes before the echo statement so that it will print in Czech.

Comment: You don't need to echo setlocale(..) statement. Apart from that it seems to be worked fine, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the date in a different format you could use `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` like shown in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)